# Как убрать галочку "Use androidx.* artifacts" в Android Studio 3.4.2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

В старых версиях Android Studio был флажок "Backwards Compatibility", в Android Studio 3.4.2 его уже нет, зато появился "Use androidx.* artifacts", галочку с которого снять нельзя. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tools->Sdk Manager->Appearence & Behavior->System Settings->Android Sdk
```

Там нужно снять галку с Android 9.+ (Q)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Нужно было убрать галочку Android 9.+(Q) в Tools -> SDK Manager-> Apperance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK-> SDK Platforms